# How can I resolve a "no such file or directory" in perl?

Tags: perl

I've been working on a script for the last 2 weeks that has been running just fine. Suddenly yesterday, it stopped working.

I was using the code `mkdir -p $somepath`. It started hanging so I inserted an "or die". Then I figured that this error might be due to me not checking if it already exists so I changed the code to 
`unless (-e $somepath) {system ("mkdir -p $somepath") or die "Couldn't make $somepath: $!"
};`

NOTE: I have also done this using perl mkdir without system but I tried everything since nothing was working.

Here's the strange part. It actually IS creating the directory and then dying with the error 
`Couldn't make "insert path here": No such file or directory`

So it seems like it is doing the mkdir, checking that it does exist, and then dies. I don't know why it started doing this because I hadn't changed a single thing to my script and it was working fine yesterday. Please let me know if I've forgotten to include any information.

Edit: I figured out my issue. It has absolutely nothing to do with any of the mkdirs. For some reason it was coming from enabling an option that allows a user to supply a path instead of having a direct path in the code. The dirty fix was to disable the feature for now. So the problem was occurring even before I got to the mkdir lines.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `... or die` you added.

[`system`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/system) returns `0` on success (which is false in boolean context), so your code will only `die` if `mkdir` succeeds.

Also, `$!` doesn't contain a meaningful status code if `system` reports a non-zero exit status. The whole `No such file or directory` message is a red herring.

Better:

```
system(...) == 0
    or die "mkdir -p $somepath returned $?";
```

Calling `system` with a single argument goes through the shell, which can cause problems if `$somepath` contains e.g. spaces, `*`, or other special characters.

Better:

```
system('mkdir', '-p', '--', $somepath) == 0
    or die "mkdir -p $somepath returned $?";
```

There is no point in checking `-e $somepath` beforehand; `mkdir -p` takes care of that for you.

Finally, you don't need to run a separate program just to create a directory hierarchy:

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
make_path($somepath);
```

Comment: The problem is if I don't add in the or die, the program just hangs. I figured that adding that would be good to show me at which point it is hanging. I removed it now and ran it again. Process hangs.

Comment: @sfr Then I'd run the script under `strace` to see what's going on.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but process is hanging :/ I did try strace yesterday but I couldn't really make sense of the output when it was hanging, so I that's when I tried the die option.

Comment: Step 1 is cutting all the system/shell/mkdir intermediate parts and just calling `make_path`. As for step 2: If you can post the strace log somewhere, I can take a look.

Comment: @sfr ... Wait, what evidence do you have that it's hanging at the `mkdir` step? If it's creating the directory and reaching the `die` call, that means `mkdir` is *not* the problem. It must be hanging somewhere later on.

Comment: The next step is another mkdir for another dir that was written the same way. It's making the first dir, dying, returning the error at the line, and then fails to make the dir in the next line.

Comment: @sfr Well, I've answered the question for the code you posted here. If you need help debugging the hang, I'd suggest you post a separate question (with a [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!